# -webkit-text-size-adjust for Desktop browser

Tags: html, css, webkit

Is there a way to get a similar result than using webkit-text-size-adjust on a Desktop browser?

Thanks,

Comment: The idea behind `-webkit-text-size-adjust` is to enlarge text in webpages that are not optimized for mobile. What are you trying to do with it in desktop?

Comment: zoom text on a document where I do not know the structure (it's a document viewer app)

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble with this and I know this is an old question but thought I'd answer anyways.

Just an FYI for phones, `-webkit-text-size-adjust` [doesn't work if you have a `<meta viewport>` set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust#IE_Phone_note). If you want more control on how things are scaling, you can specify `initial-scale`, `maximum-scale` or even `minimum-scale` along with the `width=device-width`.

There is a lot of good information on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).